# An 'End-to-end Solution' or A '360-Degree Solution'? Is there any difference?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-usage

Often I write about my company's services and try to make them *class apart.* The very general way of doing this is putting catchy titles or punch lines on the slides or banners of the website. Whilst *We provide the best or industry-standard solutions* is unambiguous and thus frequently used, at times, I come up with the captions...

> *A 360-Degree Solution* 
>   *An End-to-End Solution*

Do they mean the same? I think 360-degree solution is more *complete* than the latter one. Here is why...

For instance, we are a mobile app development company and if I say...

> Contact us for ***a 360-degree solution***

Will it mean that we do provide solution for your handsets? Hardware? The fact is we don't do that but ***since*** I wrote 360-degree, it includes right from the handset (device's) problem to developing an application, its usability, marketing and what not. After all, it's 360-degree solution. From ZERO, go round the circle, and back to ZERO!

Now, if I say end-to-end solution, does it mean that I just talk about ***mobile apps development*** and nothing about device/hardware or something the like?

***What is the difference between an end-to-end solution and a 360-degree solution?**

Is there anything like ***180-degree solution?*** Does it make sense in English? Is it an end-to-end solution?

Comment: I would understand these phrases to have identical meaning. That said, 'end-to-end' is a more established and idiomatic phrase. So it sounds *slightly* less obnoxious and business jargon-y than '360-degree solution' to my ears. I'd be tempted to go for 'complete'. Keep it simple!

Answer (score 5):

The difference is in the metaphor within the idiom. Different metaphors create different contexts which create different usages.

*End to end* conveys a linear sense; a line or length of some sort, and an *end to end solution* covers the complete range. In software, this phrase would mean a solution that covers each piece involved, from the client interface to the data storage and everything in between. *End to end testing* is a very common example of this usage in the industry. This idiom has a common and generally well understood meaning.

*360 degree* suggests a circle, and such a solution would cover *every possible angle*. This would likely be used to suggest that the software works on every platform: desktop, server, phone, tablet, etc. This is because software is often spoken of as *facing* a particular platform or audience when supported (e.g. *mobile facing, web facing*). Alternatively, this could be taken to mean that the software provide any and all desired functions within its domain; users don't have use anything else to do what they need. This term is much more nebulous than *end to end* and is more likely to be viewed as marketing fluff.

If you have an *end to end* solution then you've got every necessary step in the pipeline or process covered; nothing is missing or needs to be supplied by a third party. If you have a *360 degree solution*, then the solution works in all applicable environments; it covers all the angles and users can access their data from any entry point.

> Is there anything like 180-degree solution? Does it make sense in English? Is it an end-to-end solution?

No, this is not a common term (I've never heard it before), and it does not mean the same as *end to end*. You could use *180 degree solution* sarcastically to imply that a proposed *360 degree solution* only did things in a half-assed fashion, because *180 degree* means that only half of things are covered.